# bulk changing of default column values from a spreadsheet

Tags: sharepoint-library, default-value

We are setting up a folder structure with default column values, so contributors to the site don't have to manually add meta data.

The problem is, we have around 600 folders in the library, and will have 8 of these libraries.

We have all of the default column values we need in a spreadsheet, referenced to the folder structure. Is there a way to apply these on mass, to avoid human error and tedious repetition?

Cheers
Rory.

Comment: the default value is different for each folder?

Answer (score 0):

By using ShareGate, you can export/import metadata as spreadsheet to massively update column values. You can also run powershell to set default values too.

```
$spFieldType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Text
$sList.Fields.Add("ColumnName",$spFieldType,$true)
$sList.Update()

$f = $sList.Fields["ColumnName"]
$f.DefaultValue = "DefaultValue"
$f.Update()
```